# Is there a way to be notified when the ubuntu cloud images are released?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ami

I know that I can find the latest Ubuntu AMI builds at http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/, but is there a mailing list, or RSS feed, or some way to be notified of new builds? I want to be sure that my AMI builds are based on the latest patches, but I don't want to have to visit that page every day to see if there is something new.

Ideally, I would only be notified of LTS releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/rss/

does that do what you want?

The feeds seem to be updated where appropriate:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/rss/wily-daily.xml

subscribe to the LTS releases:

lucid-${MILESTONE_LABEL}.xml   21-Jul-2014 23:02   34K  Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) daily builds
lucid-Daily.xml                07-Oct-2014 02:42   43K  Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) daily builds

and you are done.